# testing GWT Module in Play application

Tags: gwt, testing, playframework

I need to test GWT Module in Play. I tried to use GWTTestCase, but, as I understood, it doesn't work in Play. Please, advice, how to test GWT Module.

Answer (score 1):

Google Web Toolkit (GWT) is a development toolkit, you can follow this [link](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/testing_gwt_applications) for the testing  of GWT Applications.